# Ajax format after submit - Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, forms, validation, request

I'm working on project, I faced some problems

If I fill all fields and then submit there is no problem and it saved to database,  but my issue if some field is empty the validation messages error appear in another page as JSON format.

I don't use any AJAX code in my view file.

Here is controller code:

```
public function store(RegisterRequest $request){
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    $user->password = Hash::make($request['password']);

    if ($request->file('avatar')) {
        $image = $request->file('avatar');
        $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/uploads/default';
        $path = time() . '_' . Str::random(10) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image_resize = Intervention::make($image->getRealPath());
        $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
        $image_resize->save($destinationPath . '/' . $path);
    } else {
        $path = $user->avatar;
    }
    $user->avatar = $path;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.user.index')->with('message','User created successfully');
```

And here is `RegisterRequest` code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'         => 'required',
        'email'        => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password'     => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'country_code' => 'sometimes|required',
        'phone'=>Rule::unique('users','phone')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('country_code', Request::get('country_code'));
        })
    ];
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: The `phone` rule is the only non-trivial thing, have you tried commenting it out?  `error appear in another page` - what is the other page, I mean what is the URL?  Is it the URL of the page with the form, where you started?  Does it make sense how you got there, in terms of your routing and form action, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Your errors should be accessible inside blade file with $errors variable which you need to iterate and display the errors.
Link to doc which will help you with the render part - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Clearly from doc as well

```
If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Also refactor the code a bit as following to run only one query to create a user instead of creating and then updating.

```
 public function store(RegisterRequest $request){
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        //use try catch for image conversion might be a rare case of lib failure
        try {
            $image = $request->file('avatar');
            $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/uploads/default';
            $path = time() . '_' . Str::random(10) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Intervention::make($image->getRealPath());
            $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
            $image_resize->save($destinationPath . '/' . $path);
            $request->avatar = $path;
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            //handle skip or report error as per your case
        }
    }
    $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('admin.user.index')->with('message','User created successfully');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , but I've already used  $errors variable in my view , and I faced same issue

Comment: if you are stuck and in hurry, then use inline validator instead to handle the request gives you more control for redirection.

Comment: try adding after hooks and add redirect in after hook that should work too, haven't test that. 

public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
       //redirect back with errors
    });
}

Comment: I've already tried, but I still have the same problem. I was not the only one who built this project. Is it possible that one of the other programmers have changed some files ?

Comment: quite a possibility. Delete your vendor folder. run composer install to install the requirements again.